# Vagrant PermitUserEnvironment

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am using vagrant to host a virtual Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I am trying to get it to use the `~/.ssh/environment` file to use my personal PS1 among other things. It does no work.

- I have `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in `guest:///etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- I have my stuff in `host://~/.ssh/environment`

I want this to be usable for many users, so I can't just put things in guest system `bashrc` file.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score -2):

Try putting the commands in /etc/profile.  Note: you may need to log out and log back in to see the change(s).